# Git workflow: whats the difference from SVN?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I have read these two papers about git workflow:

- http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/

As far as I understand, the model is simple:

1. we have a **develop** branch (ex-trunk),
2. we create **feature** branches to be merged into **develop** when ready,
3. we make **release** branch when all the features are implemented and we merge **release** branches into **master** in one commit when everything is ready (and to **develop** just for integrity).
4. Finally we tag **master** branch.

Well, a question is:

1. Is there any significant differences from this model in some other examples of GitWorkflow?
2. If no, what are the differences between this model and standart SVN development? Why we call it "GitWorkflow" - I cannot see any difference with standart SVN development scheme. We can do the same with SVN. And we do :)

So is this way really called GitWorkflow, or may be there are some points I have missed?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/about/distributed

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand, the model is simple

Your understanding is **massively wrong**

- GitFlow is rather complex workflow
- GitFlow assumes a set of *families* of purpose-oriented branches (feature*, hotfix*, release*) with a lot of predefined rules for order and direction of cross-branch merges

> what are the differences between this model and standart SVN development?

1. "Standard" SVN development doesn't exist - there are at least 2 widely-used SVN-workflows ("stable trunk" vs "unstable trunk|no branches")
2. *Any* SVN-workflow assumes as few merges, as possible (SVN-merges are still some headache), GitFlow built around intensive merging between special-purpose branches

Comment: may be you can recommend me some paper on this? I really dont get where I went wrong. Yes, there are families of feature* branches, with some rules described in papers above, but whats the difference with SVN? We can do the same with SVN.

Comment: @Dymytry - with cross-branch merges in SVN you'll get most probably "merge hell" at reintegration point at some time... Just experience